# Javascript text box hover on mouse over

Tags: javascript, html, css, textbox, hover

I have a very simple javascript code that I need for my website but it doesn't work as I wished... It is about a text hover box that apears and disapears when I mouseover a button. The code works with one button but I need more of them. It seems that when I add the second button with the same hoverbox effect it doesn't work any more (it hovers only the second text when I mouse over on any of the buttons). My question is hov can I add the same hoverbox effect but with different text on each box, to multiple buttons. Here is what I got so far...

The Javascript:

```
var oVTog = 
{
    toggle: function (el) 
    {
        oVTog.container = el.parentNode;
        oVTog.para = oVTog.container.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];  
        oVTog.para.style.display = "none";

        el.onmouseover = function () 
        {
            oVTog.para.style.display = '';
            return false;
        };

        el.onmouseout = function () 
        {
            oVTog.para.style.display = 'none';
            return false;
        };

        el.onclick = function () 
        {
            oVTog.para.style.display = oVTog.para.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none';
            return false;
        };
    }
};

window.onload = function () 
{
    var l = document.getElementById('togTrigger');
    oVTog.toggle(l);
    var l = document.getElementById('togTrigger2');
    oVTog.toggle(l);
};
```

CSS:

```
a 
{
    text-decoration: none;
 outline: none;
}

div#page 
{
    margin: 60px auto;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    width: 910px;
}

.TogWrap 
{
    width: 400px;
    padding: 22px;
}

#togTrigger 
{
    border: 1px solid #bebebe;
    padding: 7px 8px;
    background: #df7623;
    color: #fff;
}

.togContent  
{
    margin-top: 9px;
    border: 1px solid #bebebe;
    padding: 16px 10px 10px 10px;
    background: #ededed;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<body id="bd">
    <div id="theTog" class="TogWrap">
        <a href="#" id="togTrigger">Lorem ipsum One</a>
        <p class="togContent">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Mauris magna. 
            Suspendisse accumsan elit non tellus. Curabitur eros justo, malesuada 
            convallis, sagittis vitae, convallis sit amet, lectus.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="theTog" class="TogWrap">
        <a href="#" id="togTrigger2">Lorem ipsum One</a>
        <p class="togContent">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Mauris magna. 
            Suspendisse accumsan elit non tellus. Curabitur eros justo, malesuada 
            convallis, sagittis vitae, convallis sit amet, lectus.
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You are using the same ID more than once. IDs are meant to uniquely identify something.

Comment: Thanks Lee for your promt answer... On wich ID are you refering ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr;

***[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upF8P/)***

---

Explanation

The reason that this does not work is that the object is used instead of a local scope and a variable is declared twice. Another issue is that some of the DOM is incorrect and it is affecting the ability to apply style correctly.

*Use local variables instead of attaching them to the object*

The object that is holding the trigger function should not be used to host the elements. Instead make them local to the trigger function. Their scope will remain local to the events you attach to the passed in element.

```
toggle: function (el) {
 var container = el.parentNode;
 var para = container.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
 ...etc.
```

*Avoid declaring a variable twice*

A variable should not be declared twice. Do not use `var` to declare a variable if it is already declared with `var`. This code

```
var l = ...
var l = ...
```

should become

```
var l = ...
l = ...
```

*Keep `id`s unique*

Ids on dom elements should be unique, and not duplicated.

should be perhaps

```
<div id="theTog1"
<div id="theTog2"
```

*Use css class names to broadly apply styles*

Your style is only applied to `id=togTrigger` with the css definition

```
#togTrigger {...}
```

You may want to assign a `class="togTrigger"` to those elements that you would like to use this feature on, and then you can have your css definition be

```
.togTrigger {...}
```

In the end, it all works out like this, working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/upF8P/

---

jsfiddle code

html

```
<div id="theTog" class="TogWrap">
    <a href="#" id="togTrigger" class="togTrigger" >Lorem ipsum One</a>
    <p class="togContent">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Mauris magna. 
      Suspendisse accumsan elit non tellus. Curabitur eros justo, malesuada 
      convallis, sagittis vitae, convallis sit amet, lectus.
    </p>
</div>

<div id="theTog" class="TogWrap">
    <a href="#" id="togTrigger2" class="togTrigger">Lorem ipsum One</a>
    <p class="togContent">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Mauris magna. 
  Suspendisse accumsan elit non tellus. Curabitur eros justo, malesuada 
  convallis, sagittis vitae, convallis sit amet, lectus.
    </p>
</div>
```

css

```
a {
text-decoration: none;
outline: none;
}
div#page {
margin: 60px auto;
border: 1px solid #dedede;
width: 910px;
}
.TogWrap {
width: 400px;
padding: 22px;
}
.togTrigger {
border: 1px solid #bebebe;
padding: 7px 8px;
background: #df7623;
color: #fff;
}
.togContent  {
margin-top: 9px;
border: 1px solid #bebebe;
padding: 16px 10px 10px 10px;
background: #ededed;
}
```

js

```
var oVTog = {
 toggle: function (el) {
  var container = el.parentNode;
  var para = container.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
  para.style.display = "none";
  el.onmouseover = function () {
   para.style.display = '';
    return false;
   };
   el.onmouseout = function () {
    para.style.display = 'none';
    return false;
   };
   el.onclick = function () {
    para.style.display = para.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none';
    return false;
   };
  }
};
window.onload = function () {
 var l = document.getElementById('togTrigger');
 oVTog.toggle(l);
 l = document.getElementById('togTrigger2');
 oVTog.toggle(l);
};
```

Comment: I think your discussion on tangential issues (still important, but not relevant in this case) makes it harder to figure out what the actual problem was (the global variable shared by the `toggle` function).

Comment: @JuanMendes - So much to cover with this question. Also note that your fiddle did not address the missing style on the second toggle. Moreover, it is suggested to include all code from your jsfiddle because the site is unreliable.

Comment: Great ! But besides the text itself I need a title in the box... How do I do that now?

Comment: The question is not about the CSS, that's also a tangential issue. There's no reason for me to paste code from the jsfiddle that is not relevant to the question. The real problem was in the code I showed.

Comment: @AlexTimuş - You could simply add in a span to do that. Maybe something like: `<span class="togTitle">Title 1</span><br>` inside of the `<p>` element but before the text. Perhaps with this style: `.togTitle
{
 font-family: Arial;   
 font-size: 150%;
}` Here is a demo with the title: http://jsfiddle.net/upF8P/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot... I wasted my entire day on this code. I am new to javascript so many many thanks. You guys were great!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're storing the paragraph to hide and the container in global variables, `oVTog.container` and `oVTog.para`. Therefore, when you try to use it for two different nodes, they overwrite each other.

The simplest solution is to store those values in local variables http://jsfiddle.net/Mchhs/

```
var oVTog = {
    toggle: function (el) {    
        var para  = el.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
        para.style.display = "none";

        el.onmouseover = function () {
            para.style.display = '';
            return false;
        };
        el.onmouseout = function () {
            para.style.display = 'none';
            return false;
        };
        el.onclick = function () {
            para.style.display = para.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none';
            return false;
        };
    }
};
```